# JavaFX ComboBox No Value in ItemCell, UpdateItem not called

Tags: java, javafx, combobox

I'm having problem with my combobox which unable to produce value, this is my comboBox;

```
 ObservableList<Item> SupplierObservableList = FXCollections.observableList(ModelFile.CurItemList);
        System.out.println(SupplierObservableList.get(0).getmName());
        ItemIDCombo.setItems(SupplierObservableList);
        ItemIDCombo.setCellFactory(new Callback<>() {
            @Override
            public ListCell<Item> call(ListView<Item> param) {

                ListCell<Item> ItemCell = new ListCell<>() {
                    @Override
                    protected void updateItem(Item Sup, boolean Bln) {
                        super.updateItem(Sup, Bln);
                        if (Bln) {
                            setText("None");
                        } else {

                            setText(Sup.getmName());
                        }

                    }


                };
                return ItemCell;
            }
        });
```

As Seen here, I'm making printing for my Obserable List, and it produce my `getname()` result, which is what I needed, but when I add into the ItemCell to produce the value in my comboBox, it wont show anything.

Also with the ability to print result, my item wont be empty, any suggestion guys?

Comment: did you verify that `updateItem` was called at all? you can debug or print values from it.

Comment: When I use `System.out.println(Sup.getmName());` inside the updateItem, it wont show anything, so yeah no value printed. That's the cause of the problem

Comment: @Serge Yeah, I tried it, updateItem wont called, I print `Success` in that place, it wont show anything. So it is not called.. What can I do?

Comment: This piece of code looks correct. So, most likely you have issues in some other part of the program which you do not show. Try to create a small example with the combo only and play from there.

Comment: Take a look at the [`buttonCell`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/ComboBox.html#buttonCellProperty) property...